# Problems with externalize figures in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, external-files, tikz-external

I have a MWE as following where i need to build a surface externalizing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        ]
\addplot3[
  surf,
  %shader=interp,
  domain=-2.3:2.3,
  samples=90,
  domain y=-2.3:2.3,
] 
{x*exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where I defined `samples=90`. In overleaf, works well, and the result is the following:
[image]

However, when I complile on my machine, the following error appears:

[image]
and the log file says:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/Externando_figuras-figure0" "\def\ti
kzexternalrealjob{Externando_figuras}\input{Externando_figuras}"' did NOT resul
t in a usable output file 'tikz/Externando_figuras-figure0' (expected one of .p
df:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdf
latex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' 
or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can 
be found in 'tikz/Externando_figuras-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll tr
y to typeset the picture.
```

The configuration of my texmaker is the following:

[image]

It necessary modify some option or modify anything in the presented code?
Thank you for the help.